# Split an Array with specific chunks size

Tags: javascript, arrays, chunks, splice

For example I have a chunks array, this array has the sizes of individual chunks.

```
let example = [3,3]; // Chunks array
let auxarrayindex = [1,2,3,4,5,6]; // Array that I want to splice
let example2 = [3,2,3]; // Chunks array
let auxarrayindex2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8]; // Array that I want to splice
```

The result that I want is:

```
[1,2,3],[4,5,6] and the second [1,2,3],[4,5],[6,7,8]
```

This is my code:

```
for (let auxexample = 0; auxexample < example.length; auxexample++) {
    finalauxarray.push(auxarrayindex.slice(0, example[auxexample]));
}
```

The result from my code is:

```
[1,2,3],[1,2,3] and the second [1,2,3],[1,2],[1,2,3]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that your slice always starts at the same index (0).

Use a variable (like `i`) that you increase as you take chunks:

```js
let example = [3,2,3];
let auxarrayindex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let finalauxarray = [];
let i = 0;
for (let auxexample = 0; auxexample < example.length; auxexample++) {
   finalauxarray.push(auxarrayindex.slice(i, i+=example[auxexample]));
}

console.log(finalauxarray);
```

You could also use `map` for your loop:

```js
let example = [3,2,3];
let auxarrayindex = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8];

let i = 0;
let finalauxarray = example.map(size => auxarrayindex.slice(i, i+=size));

console.log(finalauxarray);
```

Comment: Thanks!! a simple method

Answer (score 3):

The problem is because of the slice parameters are wrong
You can learn more about how slice works on this link

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp

It takes as first parameter the starti g position and as last parameter the ending position which is not included in the result

You can aslo use splice for this as well
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_splice.asp

Hope that helps

Answer (score 2):

Working example using `splice` instead of `slice` as I think it offers a slightly cleaner API for this particular use-case:

```js
let example = [3, 3];
let auxArrayIndex = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
let example2 = [3, 2, 3];
let auxArrayIndex2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8];

function getChunks(chunkSizes, array) {
  let result = [];
  for (let chunkSize of chunkSizes) {
    result.push(array.splice(0, chunkSize));
  }
  return result;
}

let chunks = getChunks(example, auxArrayIndex);
let chunks2 = getChunks(example2, auxArrayIndex2);

console.log(chunks); // logs "[1,2,3], [4,5,6]"
console.log(chunks2); // logs "[1,2,3], [4,5], [6,7,8]"
```